# using an image embedded in a directory of a dll

Tags: windows, c#-4.0, embedded-resource

I have a .NET 4.0 class library with a directory called Resources, with an image called `Logo.bmp` inside it set to be compiled as an embedded resource.

In my main application I add the dll reference and set a Uri to `pack://application:,,,/ResourceImages;component/Resources/logo.bmp` and then I try to get the resource stream to that resource (using `Application.GetResourceStream(myUri)`) but it can't find the resource specified.

If however I put the image in the root directory of my dll and take out the `Resources/` it can find and return the resource stream without issue.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to anyone else who might be having this particular issue, make sure that you build the string to pass into the new uri BEFORE you make the new call, not during. I changed it so that the pack: location string is all created ahead of time and now it works